# convert string of a column to multiple rows

Tags: oracle, hierarchical-data

For data like below

---

```
Col1
----
1
23
34
124
```

Output should be like below

```
Out
1
2
3
4
```

I tried the below hierarchical query but its giving repeated data

```
select substr(col1, level, 1)
  from table1
connect by level <= length(col1);
```

I can't use distinct as this is sample and main table where I have to use this query has quite large data.

Thanks

Comment: What's the exact logic behind this output? Do you need just a counter for your rows (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...)? Or is it something more sophisticated?

Comment: No actually its string concatenated of 2 characters.. like ABEK to be converted into 2  rows AB and EK. To make the question simple I just asked with numbers that needs to be broken by digit

Comment: The obvious answer here is to use `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT` but you say this isn't possible as the actual query is more complicated but you do not give a reason (or example) why not. Please can you ask the less simple question which shows an example of your actual query and why you don't want to use `DISTINCT`.

Comment: If you want distinct values in the output, you must use "distinct" in the query. Are you looking for a way to get distinct values without using "distinct" in the query? Why do you think that may even exist?